# "Adjust pH of the solution to 5.0±0.1 with acetic acid (by potentiometry)"

Tags: analytical-chemistry, ph, terminology

In a procedure description I'm translating, there's this sentence (I here quote it literally, word for word, as it is in Russian):

> Adjust the pH of the solution to 5.0±0.1 with acetic acid (**by potentiometry**).

The meaning of "(by potentiometry)" is that the personnel should use a potentiometric [pH meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_meter) diring the adjustment process.

However, I'm not sure what the custom is of indicating this in English.

Maybe "(control using potentiometry")? Or maybe one should add the word "potentiometrically":

> Adjust pH of the solution **potentiometrically** to 5.0±0.1 with acetic acid.

There must be some commonly used turn of phrase for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is very likely a sentence adapted from of one of the methods from the *[Russian State Pharmacopoeia](http://femb.ru/femb/pharmacopea.php)* (RSP), which has numerous entries for the adverb «*потенциометрически*» (Eng. “*potentiometrically*”).

For instance, there is a nearly identical match in the normative section for the preparation of acetate buffer solution, [ОФС.1.3.0003.15-1.27 Ацетатный буферный раствор рН 5,0](https://pharmacopoeia.ru/ofs-1-3-0003-15-bufernye-rastvory/#__50):

> К 120,0 мл 6,0 г/л раствора уксусной кислоты ледяной прибавляют 100,0 мл 0,1 М раствора калия гидроксида и 250,0 мл воды, перемешивают. **Доводят рН до 5,0 потенциометрически с помощью 6 г/л раствора уксусной кислоты ледяной** или 0,1 М раствора калия гидроксида и доводят объём раствора водой до 1000,0 мл.

RSP underwent a vigorous clean-up since the Soviet era when it was primarily original, and currently it is mostly translated from the *[European Pharmacopoeia](https://www.edqm.eu/en)* (EP), so I decided to take a look at the corresponding entry in  EP 8.0 (currently invalidated, but one can at least find bits of it in the internet), *Section 4.1.3. Buffer solutions*:

> **Acetate buffer solution pH 5.0.** 4009100.
>
> To 120 mL of a 6 g/L solution of glacial acetic acid R add 100 mL of 0.1 M potassium hydroxide and about 250 mL of water R. Mix. **Adjust the pH to 5.0 with a 6 g/L solution of acetic acid R** or with 0.1 M potassium hydroxide and dilute to 1000.0 mL with water R.

EP omits the details as to how the pH is controlled, but there are several phrases in the prior text

> Adjust to pH … with …, **monitoring the pH potentiometrically**

referring to the section *2.2.3. Potentiometric Determination of pH*, so I think the phrase that you have proposed

> Adjust pH of the solution potentiometrically to 5.0±0.1 with acetic acid.

is perfectly fine and will be correctly understood as a more literate alternative to something like "*the pH was determined with a pH meter*."
A couple of similar textbook-usecases:

- *Concise Encyclopedia Chemistry* [2, p. 803]:

  > The pH of a solution is determined experimentally with a suitable pH color indicator (see Indicators) or **potentiometrically**, with a pH meter (see Glass electrode).
- *Fundamentals of Electrochemistry* [3, p. 590]:

  > The concentrations of hydrogen ions (solution pH) and of a number of other inorganic ions … are determined **potentiometrically**.

#### References

1. Council of Europe; European Directorate for the Quality of Medicines & Healthcare. *European Pharmacopoeia 8.0*; European Directorate for the Quality of Medicines & Healthcare, Council of Europe: Strasbourg, **2013**.
2. *Concise Encyclopedia Chemistry*, English language ed., 2nd ed.; Scott, T., Eagleson, M., Eds.; de Gruyter: Berlin; New York, **1994**.
3. Bagot︠s︡kiĭ, V. S. *Fundamentals of Electrochemistry*, 2nd ed.; The Electrochemical Society series; Wiley-Interscience: Hoboken, N.J, **2006**.